# apt-mirror server error in client desktop while updating "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: apt, updates, apt-mirror

Unable to fetch file, server said '/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/restricted/source/Sources: No such file or directory

Any solution for this.

Comment: It seems like something went horribly wrong with you source list. Have you tried to manually modify your source list, or add another repo via cli?

Comment: apt-mirror will take time to download full contents of the repository, so wait until it finishes downloading. If still not fixed please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228313/968501) on how to configure and use apt-mirror