# Possible to run (and update) Ubuntu with only access to an APT Cacher?

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I am setting up a number of VMs and containers and I am partitioning some private network ranges accordingly.

Suppose I have guests separated into a "frontend" (192.168.100.0/24) and "backend" (192.168.200.0/24) network (some may have access to both). The "frontend" network uses NAT and so guests do have access to the internet through that. However, some of the VMs are supposed to be as much separated and so the "backend" network only allows access between the guests *on that network* and the host. DNS lookups will also be strictly limited as well as outgoing traffic from these guests.

Let's now say I have an `apt-cacher-ng` instance running on 192.168.200.1 (backend), which happens to be the host. The name `apt-cacher.backend.local` resolves to that IP address and there are no other access restrictions.

If I would adjust all my `sources.list` snippets in `/etc/apt` of the VMs from:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
```

... to (the hacky way):

```
deb http://apt-cacher.backend.local:3142/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://apt-cacher.backend.local:3142/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
```

... or choose the somewhat cleaner configuration stanza for APT:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://apt-cacher.backend.local:3142"; };
```

So summarizing the facts:

- `apt-cacher.backend.local` (= 192.168.200.1) and any *names* that may be needed by the "backend" VM will resolve fine, anything else won't
- `apt-cacher-ng` will run listening on 192.168.200.1:3142
- access from "backend" VM is limited to the backend network (192.168.200.1/24) *entirely* and netfilter rules will ensure only the services the VM offers will be available and only the `apt-cacher-ng` instance can be accessed

Will my system be able to update *all* its packages this way? (Nope, no other software will be used, or I'll package it myself.)

Bonus questions:

- Suppose the updates would work this way, is there anything else to watch out for in such a configuration?
- Is there a sensible way to deal with package repos that use `https://`? E.g. would it be viable to "simply" mirror the respective packages to a local repo which doesn't use `https://`?

Comment: I am using exactly that kind of setup your are describing for years... and it work perfectly. So the answer is a simple: yes. Did you have any issues that suggest problems with the setup?

Comment: take a look at apt-mirror

Comment: @SimonSudler not so far. The DNS aspect was the only worry. Because the backend machines would be very limited in that regard.

Comment: @s1mmel could you elaborate how that would help? One of the answers already suggested it (and I commented there), but I'm not prepared to set aside this much space _just_ for this purpose and when my machines use a largely overlapping set of packages. Also, I am not really _just_ running Ubuntu but also some other Debian-related distros and so this would add up quite quickly.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Wen using `apt-cacher-ng` back-end machines only need to resolve the host-name of the `apt-cacher.backend.local` machine. The rest of DNS resolving for the outside repositories URIs happens on the `apt-cacher.backend.local` machine. You can also use IP instead of hos-name of `apt-cacher.backend.local`. @SimonSudler

Answer (score 3):

I understand you want to completely limit access to the outside world for the backend.  The host at 192.168.200.1 is part of the backend.

**Your idea will work** but the ACNG host also needs access to the upstream repositories to proxy the request for packages for the backend (at least that's how I understand you want to do this).  Thus, the host will also need to be part of the frontend or have some other way to connect to the internet.  Alternatively, you can preload all necessary packages to the acng host repo.  That looks like a cumbersome solution for little gain, though.

I suggest you look into the /etc/apt-cacher-ng/backend* files to hardwire what upstream servers will be used.

I also suggest you install the squid-deb-proxy-client package on the VM.  This will allow you a fully transparent configuration of the VM without even fiddling with /etc/apt/sources.list.  The magic happens via avahi and /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30autoproxy.  Run /usr/share/squid-deb-proxy-client/apt-avahi-discover from one of the VM to make sure you get the IP of the ACNG host back.

If you change the sources.list files on the backend machines/VM to apt-cacher.backend.local no further changes are necessary.  If you put us.archive.ubuntu.com in there, then you would need to resolve that via DNS (it can basically resolve to any IP you like as the request will be proxied to the ACNG host).

Serving upstream repos accessible via https will require [additional configuration](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/05/using-apt-cacher-ng-with-ssl-tls/).

**Some additional considerations added a day later**

- You mentioned that you will have some locally-produced packages to install.  I assume you will serve them from $host inside the LAN.  In that case I suggest to add a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy containing `"Acquire::http::Proxy::$host "DIRECT";`.  This bypasses the acng proxy. 
  Personally, I have included this file in a configuration deb-file I install in all machines, it is among the files I serve from $host.  That configuration deb-file has another config snippet in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private.list containing `deb http://$host/repo/debs/ generic private` pointing to a reprepro repository.  Maybe this is something that would benefit you as well.
- One thing I'd also like to make you aware of is that if `avahi-browse` or `/usr/share/squid-deb-proxy-client/apt-avahi-discover` list more than one instance of an apt_proxy service you might run into an [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid-deb-proxy/+bug/1505670) depending on the version of your VM OS.

Comment: okay, that sounds great. Yep, I get that the host running the `apt-cacher-ng` instance also needs to have more access than the "pure" backend machines. Kind of a duality. And in a sense that's already implied. Either way that's fine. I just want to partition my network. I wonder whether Avahi will work, I guess I'll have to check with `tshark` what's going on. Either way, nice suggestion. I'll hold out somewhat longer to see whether other answers come along, but I think yours qualifies for the bounty to be awarded already. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.

I see no reason why avahi wouldn't work and if it doesn't, it should simply be some installation and configuration work.  Conceptually, there's no reason for it not to work on that backend LAN of yours.  After all, that's what avahi is for.

If you want to do the testing with `tshark` then more power to you.  I assume you are very familiar with and then that makes sense.  A bit simpler solution is "avahi-browse --all|grep apt" or the script `/usr/share/squid-deb-proxy-client/apt-avahi-discover` that I already suggested.

Comment: nah, what I meant is that with Avahi in the game that `apt-cacher-ng` instance probably needs more leeway in what it is allowed and equally the backend machines (mDNS != DNS). But I have to concede that in the long run this will be more sustainable than configuring _each_ backend machine explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have allowed **http tunnels** in `apt-cacher-ng` then the answer to all your questions is yes, this is how `apt-cacher-ng` is used.

After installation, on the `apt-cacher-ng` machine go to http://localhost:3142/ for instructions and http://localhost:3142/acng-report.html for reports.

Edit the configuration file on the `apt-cacher-ng` machine like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf
```

uncomment `PassThroughPattern: .*` to allow HTPS connection tunneling.

then save the file and close the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

then restart `apt-cacher-ng` with the new configuration like so:

```
sudo systemctl restart apt-cacher-ng
```

Limiting connections to the backhand network on the `apt-cacher-ng` machine is also recommended. This can be done by editing the `/etc/hosts.allow` file and adding the following line to it:

```
apt-cacher-ng: 192.168.200.0/24
```

and editing `/etc/hosts.deny` file and adding the following line to it:

```
ALL: ALL
```

also consider adding rules to the firewall on the `apt-cacher-ng` machine to only allow connections to the needed repositories links only.

You can find more in [this link](https://kifarunix.com/how-to-setup-apt-caching-server-using-apt-cacher-ng-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

---

However, if you want to have a local copy of the repositories for your clients to update from locally, then I would suggest using `apt-mirror` and `proftpd-basic` to do that on a local machine that has access to Internet and then use this machines IP in your clients' sources lists to update locally.

To do this, please follow these steps:

**On the update machine:**

- Install `apt-mirror` and `proftpd-basic` like so:

```
sudo apt install apt-mirror proftpd-basic
```

- Edit `/etc/apt/mirror.list` so it contains the repositoris of the release you want to mirror ( eg. `bionic` ) like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

and modify/add repositories accordingly so it looks like this:

```
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

then save the file and close the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- Start `apt-mirror` like so:

```
sudo apt-mirror
```

`apt-mirror` will download around **200 GB** of data and that might take some time.

- Create and edit the `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/anonymous.conf` configuration file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/proftpd/conf.d/anonymous.conf
```

and copy and paste the following to the editor:

```
<Anonymous ~ftp>
   User                    ftp
   Group                nogroup
   UserAlias         anonymous ftp
   RequireValidShell        off

   <Directory *>
     <Limit WRITE>
       DenyAll
     </Limit>
   </Directory>
 </Anonymous>
```

then save the file and close the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- Restart the `proftpd` process like so:

```
sudo systemctl restart proftpd
```

- Mount-bind the **mirrored** repositories directory to the **ftp** directory like so:

```
sudo mount --bind /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ /srv/ftp/
```

**On the clients to be updated:**

- Edit and modify the sources in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so that they point to `ftp://Update_Machine_IP/` and change `Update_Machine_IP` to the IP of the update machine like so:

```
sudo nao /etc/apt/sources.list
```

so it will look like this:

```
deb ftp://Update_Machine_IP/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse restricted
deb ftp://Update_Machine_IP/ubuntu/ bionic-security main multiverse universe restricted
deb ftp://Update_Machine_IP/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main multiverse universe restricted
```

then save the file and close the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- Update as usual by running:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time you took to answer, but nope I do not want an APT mirror. I think my question is pretty to the point regarding what I want and the piece of information I am after. A mirror would require storage (as you so candidly point out) being set aside that I do not want to sacrifice.

Comment: @0xC0000022L If you have allow http tunnels then the answer to all your questions is yes, this is how `apt-cacher-ng` is used. You can find more and also about  HTTPS in [this link](https://kifarunix.com/how-to-setup-apt-caching-server-using-apt-cacher-ng-on-ubuntu-18-04/)